# Displaying certain vms' information on Azure Dashboard

Tags: azure, cloud, monitoring, dashboard

I need to display information like page file details (for windows vms), mounting points for linux vms ofc) and servers' uptimes on Azure dashboard. I need a quick access to these details to take correct actions. There is no time for checking every single virtual machine by connecting through ssh. Can somebody explain me how to do that because I can't see a simple way of configuring this by just adding a tile